# How to develop the video recorder run in backgroundmode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, background, avfoundation

Is it possible to run the video recorder in backgroundmode on iPhone using the AVFoundationFrameWork?

If it is possible how can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802033/running-video-recorder-in-background-in-ios-4-iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS provides limitation for background processing.
So as per my information if is not possible to produce a situation in which you application is recording video while user is operating other application.

I am writing above on basis of following.

> Most applications that enter the background state are moved to the suspended state shortly thereafter. While in this state, the application does not execute any code and may be removed from memory at any time. Applications that provide specific services to the user can request background execution time in order to provide those services.

Yes, any application can provide some specific services while running in background.
for further details refer to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you think about this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802033/running-video-recorder-in-background-in-ios-4-iphone)?

Comment: You can record video in background when user is using your application. That means your application's other functions will not get interrupted by video recording process. But once your application moves in background it will be in suspended state and it will not be able to do video operation. I think in link also Yannick Compernol has assumed that and he clarified it in comment of second answer.

Comment: unless it is jailbroken app, it not possible because of app store restriction.